# Change conditional min-width CSS definition

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I found that the collapsing menu in the Wordpress theme twentytwelve that transforms into a dropdown if the screen is too narrow is based on this conditional rule in twentytwelve/style.css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    [css rules for actual elements if conditon above applies]
}
```

I currently build a child theme based on twentytwelve, where this min-width should be 885px instead of 600px.

Changing the value within twentytwelve would be easy, but isn't really a good style.
Neither would be to copy-paste the relevant css into the child and adapt it.

Is there an elegant way with pure CSS?

I'm rather certain that some workaround with a script would be possible

(yes, I am aware that there's a twentythirteen theme)

Answer (score 0):

That is the pure CSS way, however...From my favorite theme, try responsive jQuery rules:

```
/*
Responsive jQuery is a tricky thing.
There's a bunch of different ways to handle
it, so be sure to research and find the one
that works for you best.
*/

/* getting viewport width */
var responsive_viewport = $(window).width();

/* if is below 481px */
if (responsive_viewport < 481) {

} /* end smallest screen */

/* if is larger than 481px */
if (responsive_viewport > 481) {

} /* end larger than 481px */

/* if is above or equal to 768px */
if (responsive_viewport >= 768) {


}

/* off the bat large screen actions */
if (responsive_viewport > 1030) {

}
```

Or your could hard code it into the template file by adding a style="" attribute and formatting the media query you have inside of it. This will make only that div in that template affected by the media query.

Comment: I need to work around the mother CSS theme definition somehow. 
I don't think that this piece of code is particular helpful as I want to keep the actual style, but using a different width argument. So *if* I use scripting I would have to copy the style for said element with a different width and reverse the one previously set by the mother theme, as I have to do the later one anyway.
But what I asked about here is, whether someone knows a nice workaround for CSS; or an easy one via scripts other than the one I just described.

Comment: I have never seen one like you're describing. Without media queries the above is about as close as you get. Are you aware of min-width & max-width CSS rules? You could change the width:600px; rule somewhere within that media query, to max-width:885px; But I'm not too sure without seeing it. Do you have a link to share? This is why Child themeing is not good for projects with customization.